# How to find and join broken string

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, join

I have a task to search and join broken strings in configuration files on multiple servers:

Configuration file contains many parameters and a section of it has few broken lines, which needs to be joined.

Broken strings in the configuration file are like the 2nd and 3rd line in below example:

```
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24
rconfigure 
En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24
```

And it should look like, I need to join 2nd and 3rd line from above example to look like:

```
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24
rconfigure En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24
```

Hope I'm clear.
Please advise.

**Edit**:
Strings are not necessarily ending with /24.
it could be like this as well:

```
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx
    rconfigure 
    En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24
    rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx
```

Which should be changed to:

```
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx
rconfigure En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: `sed -i ':a;/24$/!{N;s/\n/ /;ta;}'`

Comment: Thank you @Costas Could you please elaborate it, just for my understanding. Also, There are other configurations lines as well in file, so I hope this will be able to search specific broken string and join it. Please advise.

Comment: It is giving me like this: rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24 rconfigure En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24 rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx/24   all in one line

Comment: `/24$/` change to `/24\s*$/`. Regarding the "other lines" it is hecessary to indicate condition of broken string.

Comment: Lines are broken only after reconfigure. "rconfigure En32zrt" is common in  all lines, and are broken after this.

Comment: It's giving me whole file in one line.

Comment: @Costas still same result.

Comment: Do you have normal IP-addresses like `10.10.0.245` or `10.10.x.x`?

Comment: Try `/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/` instead `/10…/`

Comment: Yes Ip addresses are normal. IPv4 only. Few string have CIDR value and few do not have it, few have subnet  mask as well. Only thing common I found is "rconfigure En32zrt" based on what I am filtering it.

Comment: 4.1.5   and no alias found

Comment: This has removed 3rd and 4th Octet from Ip's

Comment: Do you try `'s/^\s*//;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta'` ?

Comment: I tried : 's/^\s*//;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\n\s*/ /;ta   and later  echo 10.11.12.13 | sed 's/\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/\1/', Now trying  's/^\s*//;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta

Comment: 's/^\s*//;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta  is somewhat closer. It joins the broken lines as example, However, after this section (where broken lines exist) it combines all the lines (all the lines after) in one line.

Comment: `'s/^\s*//;/^rconfigure/!b;:a;/\sEn32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta'`

Comment: It is giving output like this: rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx
rconfigure En32zrt 10.10.xx.xx/24
rconfigure En32zrt 10.xx.xx.xx  and anything after this comes in a single line

Comment: Previous one was better s/^\s*//;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta......    's/^\s*//;/^rconfigure/b;:a;/rconfigure En32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta' not joining the required lines, and all preceding lines are joined in single

Comment: `/^rconfigure/! b` with `!`

Comment: it doesn't joins the line, however everything seems intact.

Comment: This `'s/^\s*//;/^rconfigure/!b;:a;/\sEn32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s‌​*/ /;ta'`?

Comment: yes @Costas 's/^\s*//;/^rconfigure/!b;:a;/\sEn32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s‌​‌​*/ /;ta' doesn't join line.

Comment: `sed '/^\s*rconfigure/!b;/^\s*/s///;:a;/\sEn32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta;'` do the job for me

Comment: Thank you @Costas, sed '/^\s*rconfigure/!b;/^\s*/s///;:a;/\sEn32zrt\s\+\w\+/!N;s/\s‌​*\n\s*/ /;ta;'  Not able to figure out, why it's not working for me. No errors, but it sumply doesn't join the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all output lines should contain exactly 3 words as in OP, you could do:

```
tr ' \t' '\n' <some_file |
grep -v '^$' |
paste -d ' ' - - -
```

Notes:

- `tr` turns any whitespace separators into newlines
- `grep` removes empty lines
- after `grep` your're left with a list of words each on its own line
- `paste` repeatedly combines 3 lines into one using the given separator